# How do reindex multilevel columns

Tags: python, windows, pandas

Version info:

```
print(sys.version)
3.5.1 |Anaconda 4.1.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 15 2016, 15:29:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

I have columns in a data frame that look like this (latitude and longitude are multilevel columns):

```
+------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+
| CustomerId | StreetAddress |   Latitude   |   Longitude  | 
+------------+---------------+-------+------+-------+------+
|                            | count | mean | count | mean |
+----------------------------+-------+------+-------+------+
```

I would like to get this:

```
+------------+---------------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
| CustomerId | StreetAddress | Lat_count | Lat_mean | Lon_count | Lon_mean | 
+------------+---------------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
```

I tried this:

```
newColumns = ['CustomerId','StreetAddress','Lat_count','Lat_mean','Lon_count','Lon_mean']
data2 = data1.reindex(columns=newColumns)
```

But that absolutely did not work!  I ended up with some kind of crazy multilevel columns with each letter of each string in `newColumns` being a new level.

## Update

Here are my columns

```
data1.columns.to_series()

CustomerId                  (CustomerId, )
StreetAddress            (StreetAddress, )
Latitude       count     (Latitude, count)
               mean       (Latitude, mean)
Longitude      count    (Longitude, count)
               mean      (Longitude, mean)
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if `CustomerId` and `StreetAddress` are columns or part of the index.  can you run `print data1.columns.to_series()` and post it in your question?  Thanks

Comment: @piRSquared They are columns.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Perfect, my solution should work just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
data2 = pd.DataFrame(data1.values, columns=newColumns)
```

And also this:

```
data1.columns = newColumns
```